# IE9 CSS layout issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I helped one of my friends to setup a personal business website by using wordpress.

It looks fine in all the IE browser except IE9.

Here is the URL:
http://www.vital-motion.nl/

Basically, it just all the titles do not display. Anyone know how I should troubleshootings it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the cufon script works with IE9.  Make sure you have v1.09i or higher installed in your theme or plugin directory in WordPress.

For example, to fix our custom theme on our site so H1/H2/H3 tags used the cufon fonts (they were showing blank in IE9), we pulled the latest download to our server and put in our theme's ./js/ directory as "cufon-yui.js".  Problem solved.

Download from:
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Supporting documentation about this issue:
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#wiki-faq-1

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the most recent version of [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/).

> UPDATE Oct 24: We have released version 1.09i, which is the same as
>   1.09 but **IE9-compatible**. 1.10 is on its way as well. Keep in mind that
>   you do not need to convert your font files again, **just replace your
>   old cufon-yui.js with a new one and you're good to go**.

I don't know what version you *currently* have, but a diff shows that it's not the most recent version.